# Action to transmit queued messages over a socket

Tags: haskell, queue, socket, serialization

I have this action and it works but looks rather clunky to me. Is there any way I could improve that?

```
transMit :: Serialize a => Socket -> POSIXTime -> KEY -> a -> TPSQ -> TMap a -> IO ()
transMit s time key newmsgs q m = do
     loopAction <- atomically $ do
                       mT <- readTVar m
                       qT <- readTVar q
                       let (a, b) = key  -- extract IPv4 address a and protocolID b from KEY
                       let mT' = Map.delete key mT
                       let qT' = PSQ.delete key qT
                       writeTVar q (PSQ.insert key time qT')
                       writeTVar m (Map.insert key [newmsgs] mT')
                       case b of
                              11 -> return $ case Map.lookup key mT of
                                                  Nothing -> return ()
                                                  Just messages -> sendq s (B.snoc (S.encode messages) b ) (show a) 4711
                              72 -> return $ case Map.lookup key mT of
                                                  Nothing -> return ()
                                                  Just messages -> sendqr s (B.snoc (S.encode messages) b ) (show a) 4711

     loopAction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the libraries and types you're using here, but I see a few general Haskell things:

1. Instead of `loopAction <- atomically $ ...; loopAction`, you can use `join $ atomically $ ...`. This removes the need for the entire outer `do` block, simplifying the blocks/indentation.
2. You're doing nearly-identical operations on `m` and `q`, just with different collection types. I would attempt to extract these to a higher-order function (e.g. one possible abstraction is `modifyTVar`, which doesn't exist in the library, but you can see how to write it analogously to `modifyMVar`), and perhaps define an ad-hoc typeclass to make Map and PSQ look the same.
3. Your `case b of ...` has two nearly identical branches! Unless there's some non-obvious polymorphism, then just combine them:

   ```
   let send = case b of
       11 -> sendq
       72 -> sendqr
   return $ case Map.lookup key mT of
       Nothing -> return ()
       Just messages -> send s (B.snoc (S.encode messages) b) (show a) 4711
   ```
4. `let mT' = Map.delete key mT` is redundant because the following `insert` will always overwrite that key anyway; just use `Map.insert key [newmsgs] mT` and never define `mT'`.
5. Assuming you're using [Data.PSQueue](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/PSQueue/1.1/doc/html/Data-PSQueue.html), and *the key already exists in the queue*, you can use `PSQ.adjust` instead of a delete followed by an insert.

Taking all of my own advice except the last:

```
transMit :: Serialize a => Socket -> POSIXTime -> KEY -> a -> TPSQ -> TMap a -> IO ()
transMit s time key newmsgs q m =
    join $ atomically $ do
        modifyTVar_ q $ (PSQ.insert key time . PSQ.delete key)
        foo <- modifyTVar m $ \mT -> (Map.insert key [newmsgs] mT, Map.lookup key mT)
        let (address, protocol) = key
        let send = case protocol of
            11 -> sendq
            72 -> sendqr
        return $ case foo of
            Nothing -> return ()
            Just messages -> send s (B.snoc (S.encode messages) protocol) (show address) 4711

modifyTVar :: TVar a -> (a -> IO (a, b)) -> IO b
modifyTVar var f = do
    x <- readTVar var
    (x', r) <- f x
    writeTVar var x'
    return r
modifyTVar_ :: TVar a -> (a -> IO a) -> IO ()
modifyTVar_ var f = do
    x <- readTVar var
    writeTVar var (f x)
```

Further points about what I did:

- Note I called a variable `foo` because I don't know what it makes sense to name it in your application, not because that's a good name.
- I went and defined both `modifyTVar` and `modifyTVar_`; the latter is not needed but allows the action on `q` to be defined as a simple function composition. This is perhaps an excess of specialized utility functions, but I feel it is reasonable because the experienced Haskell programmer will understand what they do simply from seeing their names.
- I renamed `a` and `b` so the variable names actually communicate what they are; this is better than writing a comment to explain them, and so I removed the comment.
- I put `join $ atomically $ do` on a separate line so as to catch the reader's eye that this is not just a plain `do` block.

Comment: does that lambda look right f I need to adjust "any" time there maybe to the current time `writeTVar q (PSQ.adjust (\time -> time) key qT)` ?